# Drop rows with repeating NaN values in Pandas beyond a threshold

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to drop rows with NaN values only beyond a certain threshold for repetition?

For example, let's say we want the threshold of consecutive rows to be four. The following example with six consecutive rows with NaN values would have all six rows dropped.

```
start                        value                
2018-03-11 09:00:00+00:00    0.8
2018-03-11 09:15:00+00:00    0.0
2018-03-11 09:30:00+00:00    NaN
2018-03-11 09:45:00+00:00    NaN
2018-03-11 10:00:00+00:00    NaN
2018-03-11 10:15:00+00:00    NaN
2018-03-11 10:30:00+00:00    NaN
2018-03-11 10:45:00+00:00    NaN
2018-03-11 11:00:00+00:00    1.0
2018-03-11 11:15:00+00:00    1.6
2018-03-11 11:30:00+00:00    0.8
```

But the following example would have no rows dropped.

```
start                        value                
2018-03-11 09:00:00+00:00    0.8
2018-03-11 09:15:00+00:00    0.0
2018-03-11 09:30:00+00:00    0.0
2018-03-11 09:45:00+00:00    0.8
2018-03-11 10:00:00+00:00    NaN
2018-03-11 10:15:00+00:00    NaN
2018-03-11 10:30:00+00:00    NaN
2018-03-11 10:45:00+00:00    NaN
2018-03-11 11:00:00+00:00    1.0
2018-03-11 11:15:00+00:00    1.6
2018-03-11 11:30:00+00:00    0.8
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `diff` with `ne` `cumsum` create the group key , then we doing the Boolean slice.

```
n=4
s=df.value.isnull().groupby(df.value.isnull().astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum()).transform('count')
df.loc[~((s>n)&(df.value.isnull()))]
Out[69]: 
                       start  value
0   2018-03-1109:00:00+00:00    0.8
1   2018-03-1109:15:00+00:00    0.0
8   2018-03-1111:00:00+00:00    1.0
9   2018-03-1111:15:00+00:00    1.6
10  2018-03-1111:30:00+00:00    0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `filter`

Pass a callable that identifies if the group has a length less than threshold

```
mask = df.value.notna()
grps = pd.Series([*zip(mask.cumsum(), mask)], df.index)
df.groupby(grps).filter(lambda d: len(d) <= 4)

                        start  value
0   2018-03-11 09:00:00+00:00    0.8
1   2018-03-11 09:15:00+00:00    0.0
8   2018-03-11 11:00:00+00:00    1.0
9   2018-03-11 11:15:00+00:00    1.6
10  2018-03-11 11:30:00+00:00    0.8
```